# Turning Dictionary passed into two Arrays

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I pass a dictionary of data from the iPhone to WatchKitExtension. What is the best way to turn the received Dictionary into two different `item` arrays?

iPhone `Data`:

```
let applicationDict = [“Item1” : data.item1, “Item2” : data.item2]
let transfer = WCSession.defaultSession().transferUserInfo(applicationDict)
```

Watch `ExtensionDelegate`:

```
var incomingData = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let item1Value = userInfo[“Item1”] as? String, let item2Value = userInfo[“Item2”] as? String {
            incomingData.append([“Item1” : item1Value , “Item2” : item2Value])
            // use incomingData to make two item arrays
        } 
}
```

I've looked at some other questions that seem similar, and it seems like something along the lines of `componentArray = Array(incomingData.values)` but I can't get that to work.

EXAMPLE:

`Item1` is cities.  `Item2` is states. So the `Item1` array would be `["Chicago", "San Francisco"]`, and the `Item2` array would be `["Illinois", "California"]`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 2 item arrays? You seem to be making an array of dictionaries from an array of dictionaries again.

Comment: @Karthik  Sure. I want to make an array for every key passed to me that has "Item1" and an array for every key passed to me that has "Item2".  And yeah I must not be doing the correct thing trying to do that, so sorry if that is confusing. Any more questions just let me know so I can make sure I'm being clear on what I'm going for even though I can't get there yet

Comment: @Karthik I added an example of what I'm talking about to make it clearer hopefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`incomingData` is an array of dictionaries. I don't believe this is what you actually want. If you're passing in a city / state pair with each transfer, then this should work in your `ExtensionDelegate`.

```
var cities = [String]()
var states = [String]()

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let item1Value = userInfo["Item1"] as? String, let item2Value = userInfo["Item2"] as? String {
        cities.append(item1Value)
        states.append(item2Value)
    }
}
```

Comment: So I did `let values1 = Array(incomingData[0].values)` but then `value1` ends up being an array of all the 0 index items from the `incomingData`.  For example, based on my example I added in my question: I want `values1` to be `["Chicago", "San Francisco"]` not `["Chicago", "Illinois"]`.  And `values2` to be `["Illinois", "California"]` not `["San Francisco", "California"]`. That make sense?

Comment: Are `data.item1` and `data.item2` on the iPhone side already arrays of strings?

Comment: On the iPhone side, I run a for loop with `let data in results!` then loop thru the `item1`s with `data.item1 = data["Item1"] as! String`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for. Does the answer make sense now? You don't need an array of dictionaries (`incomingData`), you just need to add the strings as you receive them to String arrays.

Comment: Yup thats perfect!